# How to draw a network diagram in Grafana?

Tags: diagram, grafana

I would like to draw a network diagram in Grafana.

My data are in a table of two columns: one for an id of source node; and the other column refers to a target node. E.g.:

```
 +--------+--------+
 | source | target |
 +--------+--------+
 | 00     | 21     |
 | 00     | 23     |
 | 00     | 28     |
 | 01     | 21     |
 | 02     | 21     |
 | 02     | 22     |
 | 02     | 23     |
 +--------+--------+
```

I'd like to have a diagram with nodes corresponding to the numbers in both columns and lines between the nodes that are on the same row in the table.

Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

**UPDATE:**

I have used a text panel and added the following HTML code using [`visjs`](http://visjs.org/) network library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<style type="text/css">
    #mynetwork {
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
    }
</style>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // create an array with nodes
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        {id: '00', label: '00', group: 'producers'},
        {id: '01', label: '01', group: 'producers'},
        {id: '02', label: '02', group: 'producers'},
        {id: '21', label: '21', group: 'consumers'},
        {id: '22', label: '22', group: 'consumers'},
        {id: '23', label: '23', group: 'consumers'},
        {id: '28', label: '28', group: 'consumers'}
    ]);

    // create an array with edges
    var edges = new vis.DataSet([
        {from: '00', to: '21'},
        {from: '00', to: '23'},
        {from: '00', to: '28'},
        {from: '01', to: '21'},
        {from: '02', to: '21'},
        {from: '02', to: '22'},
        {from: '02', to: '23'}
    ]);

    // create a network
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

    // provide the data in the vis format
    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };    

    var options = {
        nodes: {
            shape: 'dot',
            size: 20,
            font: {
                size: 20,
                  color: '#ffffff'
            },
            borderWidth: 2
        },
        edges: {
            width: 2
        },
        groups: {
            producers: {
                color: {background:'red',border:'orange'},
                shape: 'diamond'
            },
            consumers: {
                shape: 'dot',
                color: {background: 'cyan',border:'blue'}
            }
        }
    };


    // initialize your network!
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

The output looks as follows:

[image: Network Diagram]

**Follow up Question:**

The data I get are hard coded into the HTML instead of being loaded from my MariaDB (mysql) database.

What changes should I make to load the network data from the database directly?

Comment: I have not used it yet but have you checked the Diagram Plugin ? (https://grafana.com/plugins/jdbranham-diagram-panel)

Comment: Thanks, I had a look to that, but I from the first look I haven't found an option to load the data to build the diagram from the database.

Comment: @Thomas regarding your follow up question -> I think that is only possible if you write your own plugin (since you need access to the grafana functions)

Comment: @Tomas - If you can provide the diagram definition from a url, the diagram-panel can use this to dynamically create your visualization, and match the metrics to it.  https://github.com/jdbranham/grafana-diagram

Answer (score 3):

There is now a diagram plugin for grafana: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/jdbranham-diagram-panel

You can use the [Mermaid JS](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) syntax to draw your diagram and associate a metric with each node of the graph.

In your case the configuration would be something like this:

```
00 --> 21
00 --> 23
00 --> 28
01 --> 21
02 --> 21
02 --> 22
02 --> 23
```

each node (`00`, `21`, `01`...) being a specific grafana metric

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no panel plugin for your task (official or not)
Below is a short list of closest candidates but none is exactly what you want:

- [Sankey Diagram panel](https://github.com/kumaravel29/sankey-panel)
- [Diagram panel](https://github.com/jdbranham/grafana-diagram)
- [Grafana directed graph panel](https://github.com/karmagood/grafana-directed-replication-graph-panel)
- [Network Map Panel](https://github.com/GlobalNOC/globalnoc-networkmap-panel)

You can also use builtin text(html) panel + some JS code + graph library (ex. visjs) or write your own plugin.

Comment: Thanks @yuri-lachin, I have used the built-in text

Comment: You can try to load data via ajax call to grafana api from your text panel. Something like: `GET 'http://grafana.example.com/api/datasources/proxy/18?query=SELECT source,target FROM your_db_table`. You can look at sample urls in graph panel query inspector. Then you can generate data for visjs in code.

Answer (score 0):

As of Grafana 7.4 <sup>[1](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/02/04/grafana-7.4-released-next-generation-graph-panel-with-30-fps-live-streaming-prometheus-exemplar-support-trace-to-logs-and-more/)</sup> the [Node Graph panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/node-graph/) has been available in beta, example:

[image: Node Graph example visualization]

Answer (score -1):

Try Grafana flowcharting plugin